# What's the best tab order for a login form?

Tags: usability, forms, login

I was wondering: **Should the login button be above the "stay logged in"-checkbox or the other way around?**

[image]

My personal preference is version b as I want to stay logged in most cases. But the more important function is the login which speaks for putting the button above the checkbox.

Comment: Nitpick: Login is a noun, you want "Log in", the verb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend going in with option B. The reasons being

1. Your **login button is the most prominent call to action button** in the section and as users scan the form from top to down anything after your most prominent view point will be overshadowed. Hence if you put the checkbox  after the button users might not even notice it.
2. When a person goes to login on the page, the **impulse would be to fill in the credentials and login in quickly**. Since I dont see any option to retain his session after logging in, by placing the checkbox below the button users might not even realize that option is there as they have quickly logged.
3. People while reading forms or content will look at the quickest path to completion and hence you need to ensure the options they have are available to them are available before the completion of the form. This image [from a study](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?571) on which form layouts show better completion shows that users scan in a downward action with the final call to action being the final ending point
4. Even though **login is your primary action**, you are also e**nhancing the user experience** of the user by allowing him to stay logged in and hence it is **in your best interests to make option easily available and obvious**

[image]

I also recommend looking at examples of how prominent sites have handled the **stay logged in option**

[image][image][image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Google changed the order recently for [their login box](http://on.uiux.de/image/2Y2d0S291H27/o), btw.

Comment: this style is more inconvenient for users who tab through fields and hit enter

Answer (score 0):

The `stay logged in` is often put below the login button as it is not critical for form completion and task progress.

Given:

- Users login often
- Their task is 'to login'
- The step is nothing but a barrier for them in their journey to what is their real goal

it pays to make the form as short as possible (having the optional `stay logged in` option below the progress control).

What's more, `Stay logged in` is Klingon to technical novices - the phrase itself indicates nothing as for the function of the checkbox, and thus help often offered nearby.

Also, the `stay logged in` choice often remains between visits; it is rather a 'boolean offer' - first time users see it they either tick it or not, but the choice is largely unchanged between visits.

Taken all into account, the version with the option below the login button would be considered more usable.

Answer (score 0):

I will be the first one to offer an opinion for below. There are pros and cons to both.

Sure you can design by convention , but i feel you should only do that if there isnt any affordances to help a user. Here no matter where you put it they can see it and click it if they like.

**Why put the login above?**

For someone who likes using the keyboard and tab more, they can click once type their 1. username , 2. tab type password, 3. tab and click enter to log in.

if this is something where users would log in often and not want to save their password (stock account, bank account, something used at work or common computers), I would give this a plus to thus case.

If a user wants to stay logged in you can put a cookie there and keep it checked no matter where it is.

The only downside is that by putting it below someone may not notice it. But i think they are just as likely to not notice it in either location. some user testing could confirm it.